# FFMpeg Add multiple Gifs/Watermarks to a video

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add various Gifs/Watermarks to a video, but I'm having a problem getting it to work properly.

We're assuming the video is 60 seconds long and I'm adding one Gif image. The output looks correct, the sound is on, the gif animates, and the video doesn't stop. here is the code:

```
            add("-i")
            add("inputVideo.mp4")
            add("-stream_loop")
            add("-1")
            add("-i")
            add("gif_1.gif")
            add("-filter_complex")
            add("[0][1]overlay=x=18:y=461:shortest=1[out]) 
            add("-map")
            add("[out]")
            add("-map")
            add("0:a?") 
            add("-qscale:v")
            add("1")
            add("-preset")
            add("ultrafast")
            add("outputVideo.mp4")
```

When I try to add multiple GIFs, the video plays and the sound is on, one GIF animates, but the rest of the GIFs finish animating very early. this is the code

```
            add("-i")
            add("inputVideo.mp4")
            add("-stream_loop")
            add("-1")
            add("-i")
            add("gif_1.gif")
            add("-i")
            add("gif_2.gif")
            add("-i")
            add("gif_3.gif")
            add("-filter_complex")
            add("[0][1]overlay=x=47:y=106:shortest=1[t1];[t1][2]overlay=x=551:y=1190[t2];[t2][3]overlay=x=-82:y=1279[out]) 
            add("-map")
            add("[out]")
            add("-map")
            add("0:a?") 
            add("-qscale:v")
            add("1")
            add("-preset")
            add("ultrafast")
            add("outputVideo.mp4")
```

What can I do to have all random GIFs added to animate while the video is playing for the full 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching feature of [`image2` format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)

Instead of

```
-stream_loop -1 -i gif_1.gif -i gif_2.gif -i gif_3.gif
```

try

```
-framerate 1 -i gif_%d.gif
```

This will *sequentially* show `gif_1.gif`, `gif_2.gif`, `gif_3.gif` etc., 1 second apart. To change the display duration, set `-framerate` to 1/duration (so 0.5 for 2 seconds, 0.1 for 10 seconds, etc.)

Comment: It did not help me. I tried the way you motioned but it stopped working at all

Comment: Post the FFmpeg logs if you still want me or others to diagnose your issue